# Can I share the model between two openapi clients?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi

I have two spec files: `regular.yaml` and `additions.yaml` with references the first one. I want to generate two clients but have them share the model for simplicity

However when I generate the clients as follows (`generateClientAdditions` is similar just replace regular with additions) I get two sourcefolders with each having the package `com.myapi.client.model` but some classes have an error because the type is already defined (in the other sourefolder)

```
task generateClientRegular(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {

    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = regularYml
    outputDir = "$buildDir/client/regular".toString()
    apiPackage     = "com.myapi.client.regular.api"
    invokerPackage = "com.myapi.client.regular.invoker"
    modelPackage   = "com.myapi.client.model"
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "legacy",
        library    : "resttemplate"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to use a shared model for two clients(or servers)?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the same `outputDir` for both generators seems to work however only one `StatusApi` will be generated.